# give name of city where every book is stored

Tags: mysql, sql, database

the schema:

```
author(authorname, citizenship,birthyear)

book(ISBN, title, authorname)

topic(ISBN, subject)

branch(libname, city)

instock(ISBN, libname, quantity)
```

kindly give query of following problems

1)give name of city where all books can be found (min one book from each title).

2)give author and title  of each book having highest copies in melbourne branch.

i tried to solve the second one , correct me if i'm wrong

```
SELECT author,title
FROM book INNER JOIN instock ON book.ISBN=instock.ISBN
GROUP BY city HAVING city='melbourne' AND quantity= (
    SELECT MAX(quantity)
    FROM instock
    GROUP BY city Having city='melbourne'
)
```

Comment: *"kindly give query of following problems"* - Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you.  *"correct me if i'm wrong"* - What happens when you test your solution?  Does it produce the expected results?

Comment: that's the 2nd problems answer i figured out, i think there is a better way to solve it. besides i don't know how to solve the first one

Comment: #1 is a simple `JOIN` operation. #2 is a simple `JOIN` with possibly a CTE. Your answer should work, but it is almost a brute-force way to get at the answer. Also, please see David's comment about the purposes of Stack Overflow and how it relates to homework questions. EDIT: Never mind, your #2 won't work because you're `GROUP`ing on a field that you haven't `SELECT`ed.

Comment: Also, look up the differences and the usages of `HAVING` vs `WHERE`, and how `GROUP BY` works with aggregation. I don't intend to sound harsh, and I want to encourage new users to come to Stack Overflow, but this question shows very little initiative towards learning what it is that you even want to ask about. Please put in a little more effort to working through this problem, and people will be a lot more likely to help you with your homework. Keep in mind that the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to give you the answer, but instead to help you learn how to get the answer you're after.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tried something I came up with the following queries to help:

> Give name of city where all books can be found (min one book from each
>   title).

```
SELECT A.city
FROM branch A JOIN instock B
ON A.libname=B.libname
WHERE B.quantity>0
GROUP BY A.city
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.ISBN)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ISBN) FROM book);
```

> Give author and title of each book having highest copies in melbourne
>   branch.

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.ISBN, H.title, H.authorname
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(C.totalQuantity) maxTotalQuantity
    FROM
    (SELECT A.ISBN, SUM(B.quantity) totalQuantity
     FROM branch A JOIN instock B
     ON A.libname=B.libname
     WHERE LOWER(A.city)='melbourne'
     GROUP BY A.ISBN) C) F 
JOIN 
    (SELECT D.ISBN, SUM(E.quantity) totalQuantity
     FROM branch D JOIN instock E
     ON D.libname=E.libname
     WHERE LOWER(D.city)='melbourne'
     GROUP BY D.ISBN) G
ON F.maxTotalQuantity=G.totalQuantity
JOIN book H 
ON H.ISBB=G.ISBN;
```

Comment: If anyone else comes to look at these answers, I can't recommend either of these. They are both much more convoluted than the original question indicates, and I'm not sure the first one will return exactly what the OP was looking for. Regardless, 1) the solutions should both be fairly simple queries, 2) despite requests, the OP showed minimal effort to attempt this homework and 3) these answers will teach poor habits to someone who needs a better grasp of querying basics.

Comment: @Shawn write your answer and teach us both, I'm always happy to learn.

Comment: @cdaiga I do apologize. After re-reading my comment, I was much more snippy-sounding than I intended to be, but I still don't think OP put much effort in. And I will admit I was wrong about the first query. I misread the question the first time through. Ultimately, I think it did require that subquery count. The second one, though, didn't need both subqueries. My solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91388ce/1. I always forget that MySQL doesn't play nice with CTEs or window functions.

Comment: @cdaiga  Also, it won't let me remove my downvote unless the answer is edited. I will gladly remove it if it's edited.